Pop specific item from Python set and get default if not exists
Is there a simple method, maybe a one-liner, to pop an item from Python set, and get default value if it does not exist?
It could be done in four lines of code and two hash table lookups:
def pop_default(coll: set, v, default=None):
    if v not in coll:
        return default
    coll.remove(v)
    return v

Can this function be re-written and

Be more compact, preferably a one-liner,
Be at least same efficient?

Function usage example:
s = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
assert pop_default(s, 'a') == 'a'
assert s == {'b', 'c'}

assert pop_default(s, 'x') == None
assert s == {'b', 'c'}

Solution
Two separate improvements were proposed by @jonrsharpe and @TimurShtatland.
One-liner
def pop_default(s: set, v, default=None):
    return s.remove(v) or v if v in s else default

A clear winner. Same efficiency, one line of code.
Alternative for some rare cases: exception-based
def pop_default(coll: set, v, default=None):
    try:
        coll.remove(v)
        return v
    except KeyError:
        return default

This solution is ~5 times slower in @nocomment 's test but is faster if exception is not raised.

Calling it "pop" is perhaps confusing as there's already a pop method which removes an arbitrary value. Aside from that, "better" how?

Is s.remove(v) or v if v in s else default better? It's one line.

Your code is perfectly clear, I don't know why you're looking for something "more elegant". Unless you're playing code golf, there's no award for one-liners.

@jonrsharpe yes, exactly like this.

This is a very strange construct. I don't think I've ever seen a use case for it.

@user2357112 this is useful when you consume from set that can contain some known values, e.g. options or flags.

@Michael: Even then, sets aren't the usual data structure for that, and an if thing in set test would be more common than destructive consumption.

@user2357112 yes, this is a relatively rare case, and it was the first time I asked myself why set.pop() has no args and there is no alternative to dict.popitem().

(It's quite common for other languages' equivalents of set.discard to return some sort of "was it there" indicator, but I've never seen one that works like this.)

@user2357112 dict.pop() is the closest alternative.

"Same efficiency' - Almost. It does have an additional truth value test. - "~5 times slower in general case' - Depends on what you mean with "general case". It was ~5 times slower in my test, but that was a worst case for it. (My point with it was really to say "it depends", as Timur had said "it is more efficient".)

This requires only a single lookup into the set, so in rare corner cases it is somewhat more efficient. Unfortunately, more generally (which includes the OP case, as well as many realistic cases), it is less efficient. Also, it is longer by one line. Note that I renamed the method to avoid clashing with the existing pop method.
def remove_with_default(coll: set, v, default=None):
    try:
        coll.remove(v)
        return v
    except KeyError:
        return default

s = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
assert remove_with_default(s, 'a') == 'a'
assert s == {'b', 'c'}

assert remove_with_default(s, 'x') == None
assert s == {'b', 'c'}

Benchmark
(Thanks to no comment for the benchmarking code and to the OP for the suggestion of the corner case)
from timeit import repeat
from random import randrange
import numpy as np

def pop(coll: set, v, default=None):
    if v not in coll:
        return default
    coll.remove(v)
    return v

def remove_with_default(coll: set, v, default=None):
    try:
        coll.remove(v)
        return v
    except KeyError:
        return default

set_size = 10
num_reps = 10**5

print("OP case:")
for f in [pop, remove_with_default] * 3:
    s = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
    t = 1e9 / num_reps * np.mean(repeat("f(s, 'a')", number=num_reps, globals=globals()))
    print(f'{t:0.1e} ns ', f.__name__)

print("more realistic case:")
for f in [pop, remove_with_default] * 3:
    t = 1e9 / num_reps * np.mean(repeat("s = set(range(set_size)); [f(s, randrange(set_size)) for i in range(set_size)]", number=num_reps, globals=globals()))
    print(f'{t:0.1e} ns ', f.__name__)

print("corner case:")
for f in [pop, remove_with_default] * 3:
    t = 1e9 / num_reps * np.mean(repeat("s = set(range(set_size)); [f(s, i) for i in range(set_size)]", number=num_reps, globals=globals()))
    print(f'{t:0.1e} ns ', f.__name__)

Results:
OP case:
6.4e+01 ns  pop
1.7e+02 ns  remove_with_default
3.3e+01 ns  pop
1.6e+02 ns  remove_with_default
3.3e+01 ns  pop
1.6e+02 ns  remove_with_default
more realistic case:
2.8e+03 ns  pop
3.4e+03 ns  remove_with_default
2.8e+03 ns  pop
3.3e+03 ns  remove_with_default
2.8e+03 ns  pop
3.4e+03 ns  remove_with_default
corner case:
8.2e+02 ns  pop
7.4e+02 ns  remove_with_default
8.2e+02 ns  pop
7.1e+02 ns  remove_with_default
8.5e+02 ns  pop
7.3e+02 ns  remove_with_default


Yes, this is better for large sets.

This is ~5 times slower than the OP's in my benchmark.

@Michael What's the relevance of the set size?

@nocomment the size of the hash table (lookup time) + hit/miss rate related to exception construction overhead

@Michael: Lookup time and hit/miss rate don't scale with set size like that. (Even if you account for larger sets being less likely to have all the data in cache, the data would definitely be in cache for the second lookup.)

@user2357112 I appreciate your clarification. I was not clear, by hit/miss rate I meant the rate of calls when element is in set/not in set. Consider the corner case when we are destructively iterating set with e.g. 1e9 elements and none of calls involves missing ones. In my example it will lead to 2 hash table lookups, in this example it's 1 lookup and exception is never raised.
